# Facing 401 issue after publish a skill merged bot in azure

Tags: c#, .net, botframework, azure-bot-service, bot-framework-composer

I have created one action bot (which can create ticket, tell me the description of the ticket). I have published that bot in azure. After that I have created one FAQ bot using QnA Maker, Knowledge Base and LUIS. Now I have published this FAQ bot as a Skill. Now I want to merge this to bot. For that I have added the FAQ bot skill to the Action Bot. And in Skill Configuration I have given the parent bot (Action Bot) url as "skill host endpoint url". Ex: "https://api-demobotresource.azurewebsites.net" this is my Action Bot url , and "https://FAQ-Demo.azurewebsites.net/api/messages" this is my Skill endpoint url. So I have given skill host endpoint url as "https://api-demobotresource.azurewebsites.net/api/skills". After publishing the merged bot in azure when I try to check it in web-chat, the Skill bot is not working properly. It is throwing 401 error.

I have taken the help of this article https://microsoft.github.io/botframework-solutions/help/known-issues/ . Still I am facing the same issue.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you configued the `allowedCallers` property in the skill? This should be the ID of the calling (Action Bot) bot.

Comment: Yes I have added that one also.

Answer (score 0):

The listed Error: 401 is getting triggered due to Authentication Failure and this can be due to the following 2 reasons:

1. Invalid Microsoft App ID & Password
2. Incorrect “https” settings
   As part of the solution, we need to enable the “https” settings along with inserting correct Microsoft App ID & Passwords.

If the above solution is already tried but ends in the same error, then we can try Deleting all the existing files every time we are updating or modifying our BOT Code. These steps would help in redeploying the Web APIs.

Comment: Hi SairamTadepalli-MT thank you for the response. The App ID and Password is okay. The bot is working fine using Ngrok (locally). But to deploy in azure we have to give Parent_Url/api/Skills as the skill host endpoint url. Here the problem starts. The action bot is working fine but skill is throwing this error.